# Astroscrappy not working on multiprocessing Jupyter

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, jupyter, astropy

I have some multiprocessing code here that tries to run multiple astroscrappy processes at once. However, everything stops when it actually has to call astroscrappy. I am running this in a jupyter notebook.

```
def a_test(i, q):
    import astroscrappy
    print(1)
    path = i
    s = fits.getdata(path)
    print(2)

    print(2.5)
    a = astroscrappy.detect_cosmics(s)
    print(3)
    q.put([a, i])
bundle = []
import multiprocessing as mp
queue = mp.Manager().Queue()

processes = [] 
for k, item in enumerate(paths):
    processes.append(mp.Process(target=a_test, args=(item, queue)))
    
# Run processes
for p in processes:
    p.start()
for p in processes:
    bundle.append(queue.get())
```

It will only print out 1, 2, 2.5, but not 3 which comes after calling astroscrappy. Any ideas why it won't work?

Comment: What is `paths`? I get an error running your code `NameError: name 'paths' is not defined`

Comment: path is a path on your file system to any .fits file

Comment: can u share a sample .fits file? Also, do you get any error message?

Comment: I tried with a sample fits file and removed the multiprocessing logic. After that, I was getting output as 1,2,2.5 and an error: `ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (4,200,200) into shape (4,200)`. Can you also try without multiprocessing and see if you get any error message?

Comment: I have some code that doesn't use multiprocessing. I don't get an error, but it is slower.

Comment: Not sure how you are getting that error but it could be that your fits file might have extra data in it? Mine comes with 1 data and 1 header

Comment: Try one of the int 3 fits from here https://irsa.ipac.caltech.edu/ibe/data/wise/allwise/p3am_cdd/00/0000/0000m016_ac51/

Comment: @JamesHuang can you add the code where `paths` and `fits` were declared?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at astroscrappy's github here: https://github.com/astropy/astroscrappy, you will see that it already uses its own multiprocessing called OpenMP. Trying to further multiprocess this kind of function will yield marginal results or not even anything at all. Your best bet is to just stick with the speed you already have, which should be fairly quick.

Answer (score 1):

The code is spawning multiple processes and each process must be given proper time to terminate. Calling `join()` for each process does exactly that. I tested the code below for 3 files and was able to observe concurrency of processes. The execution time is 7-9 seconds on my machine.

```
import time
import astroscrappy
from astropy.io import fits
import multiprocessing as mp

bundle = []
processes = []
paths = [r"C:\Users\xxxx\FITS\sample.fits", r"C:\Users\xxxx\FITS\sample1.fits", r"C:\Users\xxxx\FITS\sample2.fits"]

def a_test(i,q):    
    print(1)
    path = i
    s = fits.getdata(path)
    print(2)

    print(2.5)
    a = astroscrappy.detect_cosmics(s)
    print(3)    
    q.put([a, path])

if __name__ == '__main__':  
    start = time.time()          
    queue = mp.Manager().Queue()    
    for item in paths:
        processes.append(mp.Process(target=a_test, args=(item,queue)))

    # # Run processes
    for p in processes:
        p.start()
    for p in processes:        
        bundle.append(queue.get())

    #wait for child processes to finish
    for p in processes:      
        p.join()   
    
    end = time.time()

    print(f'Execution time: {end - start} seconds')
```

Output:

```
1
2
2.5
1
2
2.5
1
2
2.5
3
3
3
Execution time: 9.224327564239502 seconds
```

This code does not run in jupyter notebook out of the box. To read why `multiprocessing` does not work as expected in jupyter notebook, you can refer to [this discussion](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/941).

But there is a workaround. To make this code work in Jupyter notebook, you need to invoke `a_test` from a separate python file. For example, I created a python file(in the same directory where your notebook is running) called *functest.py* with the following code:

```
import astroscrappy
from astropy.io import fits

def a_test(*args):        
    path = args[0]   
    s = fits.getdata(path)
    a = astroscrappy.detect_cosmics(s)
    return [a,path]
```

Now, run the code below in your notebook. Note that, I've used a `Pool` instead of `Process` and the output will not have print statements  from `a_test` such as 1,2,2,5 etc. I have removed them from `a_test` deliberately because they will not print to the Jupyter notebook output. Instead, I've printed out `bundle` to verify the processing.

```
import time
import multiprocessing as mp
import functest as f

paths = [r"C:\Users\xxxx\FITS\sample.fits", r"C:\Users\xxxx\FITS\sample1.fits", r"C:\Users\xxxx\FITS\sample2.fits"]

def main():
    t1 = time.time()
    pool_size = len(paths)
    with mp.Pool(processes=pool_size) as pool:
        bundle = pool.map(f.a_test, [item for item in paths]) 
    print(bundle)
    print(f"Execution time: {time.time() - t1} seconds")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output:

```
[[(array([[False, False, False, ..., False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, ..., False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, ..., False, False, False],
       ...,
       [False, False, False, ..., False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, ..., False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, ..., False, False, False]]), array([[4.8158903, 4.808729 , 4.7792015, ..., 4.6927767, 4.7188225,
        4.706318 ],
       [4.765932 , 4.75....
Execution time: 8.333278179168701
```

Another alternative to `multiprocessing` is the `concurrent.futures` module which runs in jupyter notebook without any issues. The below code can be run in jupyter notebook. I was able to bring down the execution times to 5-6 seconds.

```
import time
import astroscrappy
from astropy.io import fits
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

paths = [r"C:\Users\xxxx\FITS\sample.fits", r"C:\Users\xxxx\FITS\sample1.fits", r"C:\Users\xxxx\FITS\sample2.fits"]

def a_test1(*args):    
    print(1)
    path = args[0]
    s = fits.getdata(path)
    print(2)
    print(2.5)
    a = astroscrappy.detect_cosmics(s)
    print(3)
    return [a, path]


def main():
    t1 = time.time()
    n_threads = len(paths)    
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(n_threads) as executor:        
        futures = [executor.submit(a_test1, item) for item in paths]
        bundle = [future.result() for future in futures]
    print(bundle)  
    print(f"Execution time: {time.time() - t1}")

if __name__ == '__main__':  
    main()
```

Output:

```
1
1
1
2
2.5
2
2.5
2
2.5
3
3
3
[[(array([[False, False, False, ..., False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, ..., False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, ..., False, False, False],
       ...,
       [False, False, False, ..., False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, ..., False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, ..., False, False, False]]), array([[4.8158903, 4.808729 , 4.7792015, ..., 4.6927767, 4.7188225,
        4.706318 ]....
Execution time: 5.936185836791992
```

Another option is to use the `threading` module. Here's a simple example which can be run in jupyter. I get execution times in the order of 5-6 seconds.

```
import time
import astroscrappy
from astropy.io import fits
from threading import Thread

paths = [r"C:\Users\xxxx\FITS\sample.fits", r"C:\Users\xxxx\FITS\sample1.fits", r"C:\Users\xxxx\FITS\sample2.fits"]
thread_objs = []

def a_test(i):    
    print(1)
    path = i   
    s = fits.getdata(path)
    print(2)
    print(2.5)
    a = astroscrappy.detect_cosmics(s)
    print(3)    


def main():
    t1 = time.time()
   
    for item in paths:
        thread_objs.append(Thread(target=a_test, args=(item,)))

    # run each thread
    for thread in thread_objs:
        thread.start()
        
    # wait for each thread to finish
    for thread in thread_objs:
        thread.join() 
    print(f"Execution time: {time.time() - t1}")

main()
```

Output:

```
1
1
1
2
2.5
2
2.5
2
2.5
3
3
3
Execution time: 6.320343971252441
```

Note that if you don't have a requirement to process the result of `a_test` outside of that function, then you don't need to return anything from it. This would save further time.

I also ran some tests with `joblib`. I've refactored your code and shared some test results below:

```
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
import astroscrappy
from astropy.io import fits

paths = [r"C:\Users\xxxxx\FITS\sample.fits", r"C:\Users\xxxxx\FITS\sample1.fits", r"C:\Users\xxxx\FITS\sample2.fits"]

def a_test(i):    
    print(1)
    path = i   
    s = fits.getdata(path)
    print(2)
    print(2.5)
    a = astroscrappy.detect_cosmics(s)
    print(3) 
    return ([a,i])
    
def main():
    t1 = time.time()
    a = Parallel(n_jobs=len(paths))(delayed(a_test)(i) for i in paths)    
    print(f"Execution time: {time.time() - t1}")

main()
```

Output:

```
Execution time: 6.360047101974487
```

The print statement outputs didn't appear in jupyter notebook output, but the execution time was in the range of 6-7 seconds.

In conclusion, I didn't observe significant time difference in execution times for any of the methods. This could also be because I tried on a small dataset(just 3 files). However, `concurrent.futures` showed slightly better results consistently. You can try all these methods and compare which one works best for your use-case.

Comment: It's quite strange. I ran the code, and it worked for a time. Then after I reran it, it stopped working. It also seems that this code is not running asynchronously like I would have liked, since with multiple paths, the out put is 1
2
2.5
3 repeated over and over which meant that it executed with blocking.

Comment: I should also mention that I am trying to run this in jupyter which is known to have issues doing multiprocessing

Comment: Yes, it didn’t work for me in jupyter either. I ran it via the terminal in VScode

Comment: Is there a hard requirement to run with jupyter? I’ll try with multiple paths as well

Comment: I do most of the code on jupyter, so keeping it there is more convenient. It's also important to know what works incase this happens in the future.

Comment: @JamesHuang, I edited my answer with more tests

Answer (score 0):

Using joblib's Parallel, I was able to make this code work much faster without getting stuck.

```
def a_test_parallel(i):
    import astroscrappy
    print(1)
    path = i
    s = fits.getdata(path)
    print(2)

    print(2.5)
    a = astroscrappy.detect_cosmics(s)
    print(3)

    return ([a,i])

a = Parallel(n_jobs=15)(delayed(a_test_parallel)(i) for i in paths[:100])
```

I ran it a couple of times in comparison with code that doesn't use parallel. This runs almost twice as fast. Still not sure why multiprocessing doesn't work, but at least this does.

Edit: After running it on a larger dataset with some extra adjustments, the code here doesn't actually run as fast as twice the speed. It actually is a bit slower than the synchronous code.

Comment: Note that multiprocessing is CPU bound. So your hardware configuration matters. I'm running the code on an i7 CPU with 4 cores so my result with multiprocessing is reasonably okay. Also, note that if you don't split your task across multiple processes, then multiprocessing won't be helpful, in fact, it can be slower in some cases. More details here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61900904/why-is-multiprocessing-slower-here